# Reading a datetime value from a SQLite database and assigning it to datepicker in C# using WPF

Tags: c#, datetime, datepicker, wpf-controls, sqlite

I want to read a datetime value from an SQLite database and assign it to a datepicker control.

Here is my code:

```
try
{
    sqlitecon.Open();
    string Query = "Select * from Customer_New where Cust_Id='" + val + "'  ";
    SQLiteCommand createCommand = new SQLiteCommand(Query, sqlitecon);
    //  createCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SQLiteDataReader dr = createCommand.ExecuteReader();
    while(dr.Read()){
        date_open.DisplayDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr.GetString(0));
        Date_Joining.DisplayDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr.GetString(1));     
        txt_Title.Text = dr.GetString(3);
        txt_cardnum.Text =dr.GetString(4)          
    }                
    sqlitecon.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

but it is giving this error: "specified cast is not valid". How can it be done?.

Comment: What is the format of the dates in the database? An SQLite database has no real dates, only strings, so it might be YYYY-MM-DD or MM/DD/YYYY or something else.

Answer (score 2):

If you already get a `DateTime` from the database you should not convert it to a string. Then just use:

```
date_open.DisplayDate = dr.GetDateTime(0);
```

instead of

```
date_open.DisplayDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr.GetString(0));
```

If it's not a `DateTime` but a `string`(`varchar`) you should consider to change that.

**Edit**: Also note that you are using two different columns of the query to assign the datatime to your `DateTimePicker`, so right after above line you do mthis:

```
date_open.DisplayDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr.GetString(1));
```

One of both must be incorrect. Which column is the datetime column?

Also, you should parametrize your queries to avoid sql-injection:

```
string Query = "Select * from Customer_New where Cust_Id=?1";
command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter { ParameterName = "1", Value = val });
```

(note that i have never used SqlLite, so  the code is untested)

Comment: it is also giving error : "string was not recognize as a valid datatime"

Comment: @getche: I've edited my answer. You are using two columns,  what is the correct one?

Comment: i have edited my question .now you can see second column . your query is not working

Comment: SQLite does not have a date type.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select strftime([date],0) as [date] from Customer_New where Cust_Id=?1
```

Comment: That might help, but there are too many unknowns, such as the format of the date in the database and the format of the current culture that `Convert.ToDateTime` will think is the right one to use.